# html form hidden variable not showing in php

Tags: php, javascript, html, variables, hidden

I have a HTML form that submits to PHP. There is an onChange event on a drop down box that calls a JavaScript function which writes a hidden variable into the form. This additional hidden variable doesnt show up in PHP though, why is this?

So;

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function change() {
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"blah\" value=\"1\"/>";
  return;
}
</script>

<form method="post" action="test.php" />
<select name="cid" id="cid" onChange="change();">
<option value="lala">lala</option>
</select>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
</form>
```

PHP doesn't see $_POST['blah']?

Comment: It's hard to see, where the error lies. Please paste the code where the onChange function is called. And I can't see any submit Button which submits the form. And by the way, it is: <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: OK, I have added more code to show whats going on, its a long form so I tried to cut some of the other crap out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more logical solution anyway would be to just add the hidden field to your form, and set the *value* to 1 in the onChange function.

Comment: I didnt do it this way round because I didnt want the variable to be there if the drop down box wasnt changed but this way works, so thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

You must have been setup something wrong, it dose work fine when I test that.
Are you sure you call the method before you submit the form ?

Answer (score 2):

I can´t see you executing your change() function.

Comment: As I said, the function is called by the onChange event of a drop down box, I can see the code change in the page.

Comment: I think adding the field to the DOM doesn't make the browser implicitly add it to the form it has in memory. As stated in my answer; it would make more sense to have the field in the form from the start, and set the value using JS.